# Is it possible to run the java thread in UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to recover java thread by doing the next?

```
Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void unchaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        t.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to run a `Thread` in a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException` ... provided that the `Thread` hasn't been started previously.

But it is NOT possible to start the `Thread` that was pass as the `t` argument.  That will (always) be a `Thread` that has already been started and has terminated.

You can start a given `Thread` at most once.  If you try to start one a second time you will get an `InvalidStateException`.  Always.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot run the thread that threw the exception, as shown in your code. It has already run. That's how it threw the exception. A thread cannot be started more than once.